# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :id=>"teacher_id", :school_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:school_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a rating for a particular teacher. I already added the school_id into my ratings table, but still get the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers",
>   :id=>"teacher_id", :school_id=>nil} missing required keys:
>   [:school_id]
>
> redirect_to school_teacher_path(params[:school_id], [:teacher_id])

Here is my route file, routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :schools do
    resources :teachers
  end

  resources :teachers do
    resources :ratings
  end
```

ratings_controller.rb:

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    get_teacher
    @rating = @teacher.ratings.build
  end

  def create
    get_teacher
    @rating = @teacher.ratings.build(rating_params)
    if @rating.save
      redirect_to school_teacher_path(params[:school_id], [:teacher_id])
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def get_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
  end

  private

    def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:easiness, :helpful, :clarity, :comment,
      :teacher_id, :school_id)
    end
end
```

ratings/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Teacher Rating</h1> <%= form_for([@teacher, @rating]) do |f| %>   <p>
    <%= f.label :clarity %>
    <%= f.text_field :clarity %>   </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :easiness %>
    <%= f.text_field :easiness %>   </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :helpfulness %>
    <%= f.text_field :helpfulness %>   </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>   </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>   </p> <% end %>
```

rating.rb:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher, dependent: :destroy
end
```

teacher.rb:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :ratings

  def name
    "#{firstName} #{middleName} #{lastName}"
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

school.rb:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teachers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Comment: please check your params in create action wether params[:school_id] is coming or not and please change       redirect_to school_teacher_path(params[:school_id], params [:teacher_id])

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mr. raje. I edited that line, however, now I get the error: {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :id=>"8", :school_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:school_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
redirect_to school_teacher_path(params[:school_id], [:teacher_id])
```

You are passing the `params[:school_id]` variable, and then an array containing the symbol `:teacher_id`.

I suspect you really intended to use something like this:

```
redirect_to school_teacher_path(params[:school_id], params[:teacher_id])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mr. Jon. But, now I get the error: 
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :id=>"8", :school_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:school_id]

Comment: Well then you don't have a `school_id` within your params variable. Somewhere in your `create` action you need to find the `school_id` you need to pass into the route helper, or you need to fix whatever submitted your create request such that it sends in the school_id with the rest of the data.

Comment: I added this line into the create action '@school = School.find(params[:school_id])'. Then, I get error: Couldn't find School with 'id'=

Comment: Yep - you still don't have a `school_id` in your params hash.

Comment: So, what cause the error, sir? I am learning Rails and this is my first project.

Comment: You need to either include the `school_id` in your params hash (add it to the form as a hidden tag or something) or ... you need another way of finding the school_id. Perhaps using an association like `@teacher.school`

Comment: Will it solve my problem if I put ratings resources inside of schools and teachers resources?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95332/discussion-between-jon-and-nevergiveup1989).